# Is this valid JSON for reading/parsing multiple objects?

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to represent a collection of objects within a JSON string, and would like to know if the format below is correct:

```
"books"
{
    "001"
    {
        "title"        "Title 1"
        "author"       "Author 1"
        "dimension"
        {
            "height"   "#cm"
            "width"    "#cm"
        }
    }
    "002"
    {
        "title"        "Title 2"
        "author"       "Author 2"
        "dimension"
        {
            "height"   "#cm"
            "width"    "#cm"
        }
    }
}
```

Is the string above valid `JSON` data? I wanted to represent it like this:

### Book Lists

```
Book Title | Book Author |    Book Dimension   | Book ID
 Title 1   |   Author 1  | Height:#cm;Width#cm |   001

 Title 2   |   Author 2  | Height:#cm;Width#cm | 002
```

Comment: That string is not valid JSON.  JSON objects are in the format `{ "name1" : value1, "name2" : value2, .., "nameN" : valueN }`.  Thus 1) Outer `{}` are missing; 2) Colons between names and values are missing; 3) Commas between name value pairs are missing.  For more information, see the (very simple) JSON standard, which is here: http://json.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, your format is not valid JSON.

To represent your JSON as you would like, it would need to be in the following format:

```
{
    "books": [
        {
            "id": "001",
            "title": "Title 1",
            "author": "Author 1",
            "dimension": {
                "height": "#cm",
                "width": "#cm"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "002",
            "title": "Title 2",
            "author": "Author 2",
            "dimension": {
                "height": "#cm",
                "width": "#cm"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use an online JSON parser to help determine if your JSON data is valid or not: http://json.parser.online.fr/